# Problem with PyInstaller executable including scikit-image

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, python-3.8, scikit-image

I created an application with PyInstaller 4.3 and scikit-image 0.18.1. I installed it on a clean Windows 10 virtual machine for testing. However when running the executable (with console output enabled) it displays the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rolling_ball_cy: The specified module could not be found.
[4920] Failed to execute script main
```

I tried adding `skimage.restoration._rolling_ball_cy` to the hidden imports in `setup.py` but that didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: what pyinstaller exceution command did you use?

Comment: Also tried scikit-image==0.18.2

Comment: @patrickgerard `pyinstaller -F -y main.spec`. The generated executable gives the error.

Comment: try this `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "C:/path/to/file"`

Comment: `Error loading Python DLL 'C:\MyApps\python38.dll'`. I'll add the DLL.

Comment: That has a more basic error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'`.

Comment: And on the Windows 10 VM it can't find `python38.dll` even if I put it in the same folder.

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks @patrickgerard .

Answer (score 0):

I used [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what is happening when `_rolling_ball_cy` is being loaded. The executable was looking for `VCOMP140.DLL`. After copying this library from the build system into the folder of the main executable on the test system it worked.

The `VCOMP140.DLL` is part of Microsoft's vcredist_x64.exe redistributable (see [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160)).